# MUI swipeable drawer stuttering on height resize

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The wipeable drawer from MUI has this issue when the view height is changed it stutters to its bottom position.

It can be replicated in their sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/du4v38?file=/demo.j toggle responsive preview and change the height you swill see what i'm talking about.

If I comment out the height line in the Global component it works properly but on refresh disappears until you open and close using toggle.

```
  <Global
    styles={{
      '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
        height: `calc(50% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
        overflow: 'visible',
      },
    }}
  />
```

This is really annoying on iOS Safari as with the new update the search bar is now on the bottom and disappears when you scroll down causing the drawer to always stutter its way down.

Comment: did you every find a solution to this?